# Sending array to django via ajax

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, post

I am trying to send Javascript Array via AJAX POST to django view.

I store this array in hidden input using JSON.stringify:

```
$('#id_uuids').val(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

this is how I try to send it:

```
$.post("/ajax/generateGallery",{uuids: $('#id_uuids').val()},function(response){
    resp = JSON.parse(response);
    alert(resp.html);
},"json");
```

Browser console shows that data which is being send looks like:

```
uuids:["6ecbe35b-0b77-4810-aa9a-918fecaeef13","e41f52f7-721b-4d44-b7d6-bbb275182d66"]
```

However, I am not able to use this in my django view. I've tried:

```
uuids = request.POST.getlist('uuids')
logger.info(uuids)
logger.info(type(uuids))
```

which returns:

```
[08/Aug/2014 15:20:00] INFO [app.rest_client:307] [u'["89a26646-6000-4c48-804a-69abcc496fd8"]']
[08/Aug/2014 15:20:00] INFO [app.rest_client:308] <type 'list'>
[08/Aug/2014 15:20:00] INFO [app.rest_client:312] Generate HTML gallery for photo ["89a26646-6000-4c48-804a-69abcc496fd8"]
```

So, Django treats very list sent as single element. How can I force python code to treat this data as list and be able to iterate on?

Comment: The problem is that you stringify the array, and it's submitted as string, this is not a Django issue but rather how you handle values in JS.

Answer (score 1):

try to JSON-decode the posted data

```
uuids = json.loads(request.POST.get('uuids'))
```

that is if you loaded some json module before, e.g.

```
import simplejson as json
```